# What is being said in this video?

Tags: vocabulario

My friend sent me this video because he thought it was funny, but now I am curious as to what is being said in the video. I asked one of my friends that speaks Spanish and he said it was something about how a guy didn't have tortillas for his quesadillas, so he went to the store.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=veRx-MbW_rI&t=5s

Comment: That's in the sense of being very hungry, chingarse, chimparse, zamparse, devorarse, engullirse, gobble it all up. He realized he didn't have tortillas for his quesadillas, so..Yes, that's right.

Comment: The last comment on the video, by "Tap Waterr", says more or less what the video is about. The reason why some people may find that video funny (I guess) is the way he speaks together with the sheer amount of inappropriate language that the video contains.

Comment: @wimi heh i was going to ask my spanish teacher about it, but i guess i shouldnt...

Comment: https://dle.rae.es/jambarse,
tragar = comer > chingar, zampar, 
got the cravings for + sth = se le atojó + verb + sth, le dieron ganas de comer(se) unas quesadillas, de chingarse unas enchiladas, ansioso/a por tragarme unas...(coloquial)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fun thing about these types of videos is the development of a story that begins as a normal situation but as it progresses, the events become surreal and absurd to the point where the irony becomes the joke of the video itself.
There is no gender to define this type of material (being just a meme)
Literal translation into other languages may not be effective as some jokes are based on puns, slang, and colloquial experiences from specific countries, even without being understood even by Spanish speakers.
Here is a literal translation of a snippet:

I was on one day in my "canton" (colloquial way of defining low income households) watching Paw Patrol and "Chingandome" (meaning Eating in vulgar language "some chips, when suddenly I wanted to" chingarme "some quesadillas with badon cheese, so I went to my kitchen and realized that there were no more tortillas.
Nooo Hijo de su "mala palabra" gives me "hueva" (colloquial way of saying laziness) go to the tortilleria "no mames, ya me la pele" (a way of saying that he has no alternative but to do something he does not want to do)
So I went to the tortilleria but when I was on the way a "morrillo" (vulgar way of saying to children or adolescents) all "meco" (vulgar way of saying idiot) well "Picudo" (expression used to define people who They boast of skills) he puts me in front telling me - "Que hovo" (Distorted form of language to say "que hubo" which in turn is a colloquial way of saying what's up? "Vato" (Hommie) I am pro because I play to the Dark souls. Huas huas